# Second Order ODE with an additional Constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following ODE,

$ x'' - ax' + b = 0$

How can I solve this equation?

Comment: Are you studying now a course in ODE?

Comment: What do you know about inhomogeneous second-order constant-coefficient linear ODE's?

Comment: I completed one ages ago but I can't remember for the life of me how to solve when you have a constant. I also can't find any notes online that discuss a solution

Comment: Hint. First show that $x' = A \, \exp(at)$ is a homogeneous solution. Let $A \rightarrow A(t)$, then $A'(t) = -b \, \exp(-at)$.  So, $A(t) = A_0 +(b/a) \, \exp(-at)$, and $x'(t) = A_0 \, \exp(a t) + b/a$.

Comment: I actually made a typo and it should have been $x$ not $x'$ in the second term. Either way the comments were helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate once (assuming the independent variable is $t$):
$$ x'-ax+bt + A = 0, $$
$A$ an arbitrary constant. This is a first-order equation, and can be solved in the usual way with the integrating factor $e^{-at}$.